# Can someone tell me how to display value rather than the id in my view detail? in my yii

Tags: php, yii

Can someone tell me how to display value rather than the id in my view detail? I have a model tickets and products.  in the tickets table I have columns with these names: id, date, operation, product name. In my product table  I have just two columns: id,name.

When I create a new ticket I use product name from product model, and in this form I get the data using a dropdownlist( the product name). but this save the id of that product. Can someone tell me how to fix this?, there is not relationship between those models, I use product table to get the product name when I create a new tickets, For example, the next code use a relation:

```
'product_name' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Product', 'id'),
```

and the view

```
array(
'name'=>'product_name',
'value'=>CHtml::encode($model->product_name->name)),
```

this is when there is a relationship, but in my case there is not relations,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your listData is like this. (Assuming your products model is Product)

```
 $list = CHtml::listData(Product::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name');

 echo CHtml::dropDownList($name,$select,$list,$htmlOptions);
```

The generated html select input options would be like this.

```
<option value="Product ID">Product Name</option>
```

To get the product name instead of its id, the listdata of your dropDownList should be like this.

```
$list = CHtml::listData(Product::model()->findAll(array('select'=>'name')), 'name', 'name');
```

The generated html select input options would be like this.

```
<option value="Product Name">Product Name</option>
```